# 301 redirect when using node.js http-server

Tags: node.js

I'm using the node.js [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server) to serve static content.

I want to set up a 301 redirect. I can't find this documented anywhere, does anyone know if this is possible in http-server without writing a custom plugin? I want to redirect http to https, and my www subdomain to non-www.

Comment: I do not use exactly this package, but what does prevent you from returning status code 301 with proper headers and body?

Comment: the http-server package is a static content server. You point it at a folder and that content will be served. There does not appear to be any way to otherwise effect the output, such as setting headers. I can write a plugin, but thought I should check I haven't missed something.

Comment: the 301 is dynamic only at client side, not server side. I post request to some URL, the server responds with static content, which is status code 301 and URL I should follow. Then I (or browser) have to send another request to new URL.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I am familiar with how this works.

Answer (score 0):

I've concluded that this is not possible. Instead I have handled this redirect in my nginx.config.